# How to rotate square numpy array of 2 dimensional by 45 degree in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array of images. The dimension is 2 and the shape is (100,100). I want to augment more data as I have only 52 set of numpy array. I want to rotate the given array by 45 degree. What should I do for that??

Suppose the array be like

```
a=[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
```

Please rotate the given array by 45 degree.

Comment: What does it mean to rotate an array by 45 degrees? What's the desired output, and what have you tried?

Comment: I'll put as much effort into the answer as you put into the question and point you towards the rotation matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.rotate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
x = np.arange(25).reshape(5, -1)
rotate(x, angle=45)
```

Output

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  4,  9, 14,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  3,  8, 12, 16, 21,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 10, 15, 20,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 18,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to maintain the same shape??
I want the same shape (100,100). For this array (5,5).

Comment: @Virtuall.Kingg then use `rotate(x, angle=45, reshape=False)` instead.

Comment: Do you know how to crop the array or lets say zooming in the center with the same shape??

Comment: @Virtuall.Kingg [`scipy.ndimage.zoom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if ndimage is in general a good solution for such matrixes. It might work for 45 degrees, but not for other angles without issues. In the example below the "20" gets changed to 0. (Numpy version 1.18.2, scipy 1.4.1)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
x = np.arange(25).reshape(5, -1)*1.0
rotate(x, angle=180,reshape=True)
Out[14]: 
array([[24., 23., 22., 21.,  0.],
       [19., 18., 17., 16., 15.],
       [14., 13., 12., 11., 10.],
       [ 9.,  8.,  7.,  6.,  5.],
       [ 4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0.]])

x
Out[15]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [10., 11., 12., 13., 14.],
       [15., 16., 17., 18., 19.],
       [20., 21., 22., 23., 24.]])
```